# Upgrade SpringXD custom module

Tags: spring-xd

I have a question about SpringXD and custom modules, that even being quite obvious I haven't been able to find out an answer in the official docs.

How am I supposed to upgrade a Custom Spring XD module. I have usually removed a module, and then re-uploaded it again through xd-shell. But it is not a convenient way, since you need to destroy all your streams using that module.

Is there a nice way to do it, ideally something like module upgrade --file in the shell. (There is not such a thing).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it looks like there is no way to upgrade custom modules I have just opened a ticket in Jira.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3392